# Adiabatic elimination in the presence of single-photon transitions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, atomic-physics, hamiltonian, approximations

I am trying to derive an effective Hamiltonian for a system that includes both periodic drives near resonance with certain transitions (that should lead to one-photon transitions) and pairs of drives that are individually far detuned from any transition but whose frequencies sum to a transition frequency of the system (so should give rise to two-photon transitions). My intuition is that if there is a pair of drives, each individually far detuned from any transition within the system, whose frequencies sum to a transition frequency that does exist within the system, and neither of which forms such a pair with any other drive, I ought to be able to replace that pair with an effective drive at the sum frequency.

As a concrete example, take a three-state system with Hamiltonian

$H(t)=\left(e^{i\omega t}+e^{-i\omega t}\right)\left\vert 1\right\rangle\left\langle 0\right\vert+\left(e^{i\omega t}+e^{-i\omega t}\right)\left\vert 1\right\rangle\left\langle 2\right\vert + \left\vert 1\right\rangle\left\langle 2\right\vert+h.c.$

which is just the usual lambda system Hamiltonian (in the interaction picture) with the addition of a resonant coupling between one of the "low-energy" states and the intermediate state. I expect that I should be able to write an effective Hamiltonian that looks something like

$H_{\text{eff}}(t)=\omega^{-1}\left\vert 0\right\rangle\left\langle 2\right\vert + \left\vert 1\right\rangle\left\langle 2\right\vert+ h.c.$

The intuition of course comes from adiabatic elimination, but in this setting I (1) can't necessarily assume that the population of $\left\vert 1\right\rangle$ is small, and  (2) can't find a frame in which the Hamiltonian is time-independent, so I don't see how to apply the usual arguments. How can I demonstrate that this form of effective Hamiltonian is correct?